# Problema conexion mysql y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo problemas con conectar la parte de mysql y PHP pero como  realmente no se cual es el problema quisiera que le hecharan un ojo para ver si tiene algun error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se los agradeceria demasiado si saben algo

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y obtengas una buena respuesta, aprende a [Como hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no adjuntes imágenes a menos que sean para dar a conocer une ejemplo, agrega el código para que alguien pueda resolver tu duda.

Comment: Así a ojo la consulta parece mal, tienes escrito SELECT*, sin espacio entre el select y el *. Revisa como capturar errores de MySQL en PHP, que te puede ayudar a entender mejor tu caso.

Comment: Sería bueno que nos muestres que tiene en el archivo db.php, además del error que dices que te está mostrando ya que el codigo que se ve, tiene buena pinta

Comment: No coloques imágenes, no todos pueden verlo. Sería mejor incluir el código puro.

Answer (score 0):

Como te respondieron en un comentario, lo ideal es que modifiques la sentencia SQL para que incluya el espacio entre SELECT y el *. Tambien me paso con algunas versiones de SQL que no me funciona bien cuando pongo el "=" para la igualdad de strings, en esos casos yo uso "LIKE"
Entonces quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE usuario LIKE '$USUARIO' AND clave LIKE '$PASSWORD'";
```

En caso de que no sea eso deberias verificar si hay algun problema en db.php
Te recomiendo verificarlo agregando un

```
if(!$resultado){
    echo mysqli_error($resultado);
}else{
    echo "Conexion correcta";
}
```

Este ultimo te va a tirar el error de mysqli que estes cometiendo en caso de que asi sea, caso contrario te va a tirar un "Conexion correcta".

Saludos!!!